# Bind several XML files with corresponding XSD schema to one Java model

Tags: java, binding, jaxb, xsd

I am currently working on a Webservice which will take several different XML files as input. Now I have to somehow bind these different XML files to the Java model of the Webservice. The problem is, that this Webservice needs to be as flexible as possible because the format of the input XML is viable to change at any time.

Is there a way to use the XSD-schema files, which correspond to the input XML, to directly bind the input XML to the existing Webservice model?

To may be make things a little more clear: EclipseLink MOXy provides the option to use several binding files to bind several XML formats to one java model. I am basically trying to do the same thing, but without having to write a binding file for each possible XML input. Instead I would like to use the XSD-Schema associated with the XML input as a binding file.

Also I cannot compile a new model or classes from a new XSD. The Model needs to be as constant as possible.

Tips or general pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!